# Add driver menu in osx

Tags: rigging, bones, drivers

I wanted to create an ik switch in blender, but I'm using a mac. At some point I have to right click on my influence bar under the bone constraints tab to add a driver, but the typical mac simulation of a right click (ctrl+left click) doesn't work.
Does anyone know how I can bring up the influence menu.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to bring up the influence menu to add drivers in OS X, press the command key + click. Make sure that your user preference is set to right click and tick on "emulate 3 button mouse".